# Sending Data Between Two Activities Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having a problem sending data between two activities - I'm new to programming and think its something to do with the positioning of the code but i'm unsure, more than likely its something simple.

I'm trying to send the number in `stepCount` to the second activity, its stored in `myText3` and is visible in the first activity and counts fine(its primitave but does the job for now).

If i set a value to `myText3` it will show that value in the second activity but it wont show the value of `stepCount`when its in `myText3`

Thanks in advance..

First Activity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



        import android.hardware.Sensor;
        import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
        import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
        import android.hardware.SensorManager;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        //import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
        //import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    TextView tvx, tvy, tvz, display, display2, display3;
    float total;
    float stepCount;
    float x, y, z;
    float xPrev,yPrev, zPrev;
    float totalPrev = 0;
    Button saveButton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });*/



        tvx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tvy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tvz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        display2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display2);
        display3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display3);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        SensorManager mgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor GSensor = mgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mgr.registerListener(this, GSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);



    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // called byt the system every 10 ms



        x = event.values[0];
        y = event.values[1];
        z = event.values[2];
        total = x + y + z;

        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                // When timer is finished
                // Execute your code here
                xPrev = x;
                yPrev = y;
                zPrev = z;
                totalPrev = xPrev + yPrev + zPrev;
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
            }
        }.start();



       if (Math.abs(total - totalPrev) > 20) {
           stepCount++;
       }


        tvx.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        tvy.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[1]));
        tvz.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[2]));

        String mytext = Float.toString(total);
        display.setText(mytext);

        String mytext2 = Float.toString(totalPrev);
        display2.setText(mytext2);

        String mytext3 = Float.toString(stepCount);
        display3.setText(mytext3);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            String mytext3;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent A2Intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                //EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                // pass the entered phone number to the next activity
                //A2Intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", tv2.getText());
                //String ph = et.getText().toString();
                A2Intent.putExtra("steps", mytext3);
                // start the next activity/page
                startActivity(A2Intent);
            }
        });








    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
    /*saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent A2Intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            // pass the entered phone number to the next activity
            //A2Intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", tv2.getText());
            String ph = et.getText().toString();
            A2Intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", ph);
            // start the next activity/page
            startActivity(A2Intent);
        }
    })*/

}
```

Second Activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView1;
    Button newButton;
    String displayCount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        newButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        displayCount = getIntent().getStringExtra("steps");
        textView1.setText(displayCount);

    }
}
```

Comment: make a log just before starting the second activity to see the values of both stepCount and mtText3

Answer (score 0):

In your saveButton onClickListener, you are creating a new String mytext3, and then passing the empty, uninitialized string into your intent. Instead, what you could do is use findViewById to retrieve the actual mytext3 in the textView, and then pass that in.

Answer (score 0):

Put `String mytext3 = Float.toString(stepCount);` inside your `saveButton`'s `onClick()` like this:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent A2Intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
            String mytext3 = Float.toString(stepCount);
            A2Intent.putExtra("steps", mytext3);
            startActivity(A2Intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: One question tho, I already put `stepCount`into `mytext3` here..                       `String mytext3 = Float.toString(stepCount);
        display3.setText(mytext3);`                                                                       Why do i have to do it again for it to work?

Comment: because you are passing the string mytext3 which you created on your onclicklistener method..

Comment: You put it into `myText3` before setting the `onClickListener`. The listener triggers at the time of the button click, not the time of creation. At that time, the value of stepCount would have changed.

Comment: Ah ok..Thanks very much guys!! A1

Answer (score 0):

```
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               // String mytext3;
               //you are giving intent a empty string here  comment above line
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent A2Intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), Main2Activity.class);
                    //EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    // pass the entered phone number to the next activity
                    //A2Intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", tv2.getText());
                    //String ph = et.getText().toString();
                    A2Intent.putExtra("steps", mytext3);
                    // start the next activity/page
                    startActivity(A2Intent);
                }
            });
```

After commenting you have to `final String mytext3` to access it in onClick.